# Armazenar resultado de promise em uma variável

Tags: javascript, node.js

Como eu posso armazenar o resultado de promise em uma variável?
A promise retorna o resultado de uma consulta do banco de dados.

```
function consultaMarcas(){
    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
      connection.query('SELECT * FROM marca',(err, result)=>{
        if(err) return reject (err);
        else return resolve(result);
      });
    });
  };
  var marcas = consultaMarcas().then(result =>{
  }).catch(err =>{
    console.log("ERRO: ",err);
  });
```

---

Meu problema é um pouco maior, porque preciso realizar mais de uma consulta e preciso passar isso para front como exemplo, aqui é o que teria no server:

```
  function recebendoValoresBD() {
    Promise.all([
      consultaMarcas().then(),
      consultaTipos().then()
    ])
    .then(result =>{
      const marcas = {marca: result[0]};
      const tipos = {tipo: result[1]};
      res.render('marcas', marcas, tipos);
    })
    .catch(err =>{
      console.log("ERRO: ", err);
    });
  }
```

E aqui está a página

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Cadastro Modelo</title>
</head>
<br/>
            <h1>Cadastro Modelo</h1>
            <hr/>
            <form action="/modelos" method="post">
                Marcas:<SELECT NAME="ativo">
                        <option><%=marcas.marca[0].descricao%>
                        </SELECT>
                        <br>
                Tipos:<SELECT NAME="ativo">
                        <option><%=tipos.tipos[0].descricao%>
                        </SELECT>
                        <br>

                Descrição:<input type="text" name="descricao"/><br/>
                Ativo: <SELECT NAME="ativo">
                        <option>
                        <option>S
                        <option>N
                        </SELECT>
                        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" >Proximo</button>
            </form>
        </body>
</html>
```

Porém fazendo isso ele me retorna um erro que é: TypeError: callback is not a function

Comment: Alguma resposta ajudou a resolver o problema e pode sanar dúvidas similares de outros usuários? Caso positivo não esqueça de marcar a resposta como aceita. Pra fazer isso é só clicar no ✓ do lado esquerdo da mesma (abaixo do indicador de up e down votes).

Answer (score 1):

Você já está fazendo isso. O valor fica dentro do then na variável `result`. Utilize o que você precisa dentro do Then.

```
function consultaMarcas(){
    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
      connection.query('SELECT * FROM marca',(err, result)=>{
        if(err) return reject (err);
        else return resolve(result);
      });
    });
  };

  consultaMarcas().then(result =>{
   var marcas = result;
   console.log(marcas);
  }).catch(err =>{
    console.log("ERRO: ",err);
  });
```

Comment: Obrigado, e como posso utilizar essa variável depois?

Comment: @victor_bez você pode fazer sua lógica dentro do Then caso vá somente retornar o resultado da rest por exemplo ou pode retornar o valor  de marcas.

var marcas = consultaMarcas().then(result =>{
   return result;
  }).catch(err =>{
    console.log("ERRO: ",err);
  });

Comment: @victor_bez no caso se for só retornar a resposta para a requisição dentro do then poderia fazer 

 consultaMarcas().then(result =>{ return res.json(result); }).catch(err =>{ console.log("ERRO: ",err); })

Comment: Obrigado pela atenção, descobri o que tinha de errado res.render('modelos', {marcas, tipos}) essa seria a forma correta, na documentação pede um terceiro parâmetro que é um callback;

Answer (score 1):

Você pode utilizar a instrução `await` para aguardar o retorno da função:

```
...
// Funções assíncronas
let marcas = await consultaMarcas();

console.log(marcas);
...
```

Adicionando ao exemplo mais completo que você deu:

```
async function resolver(req, res) {
  try {
    // Atribuição via desestruturação (destructuring assignment)
    let [marcas, tipos] = await Promise.all([consultaMarcas(), consultaTipos()]);

    // res.render(view [, locals] [, callback])
    res.render('marcas', {marcas, tipos});
  } catch(e) {
    console.error(e);
  }
}
```

Na sua rota a chamada será parecida com a seguinte:

```
router.get('/', resolver);
```

---

> TypeError: callback is not a function

Este erro indica que você está passando um objeto ou outro tipo de parâmetro para uma função que espera um `callback`. Segundo a documentação do [`Express 4.x`](http://expressjs.com/pt-br/api.html) (que deduzo que você está utilizando pela nomenclatura dos parâmetros) o terceiro parâmetro da função `render` é um parâmetro opcional destinado ao `callback` da função:

> **res.render(view [, locals] [, callback])**
>
> Renders a view and sends the rendered HTML string to the client. Optional parameters:
>
> - **locals**, an object whose properties define local variables for the view.
> - **callback**, a callback function. If provided, the method returns both the possible error and rendered string, but does not perform an automated response. When an error occurs, the method invokes `next(err)` internally.

Em tradução livre:

> Renderiza a visão e envia a string do HTML renderizado para o cliente. Parâmetros opcionais:
>
> - **locals**, um objeto cujas propriedades definem variáveis locais para a visão.
> - **callback**, uma função de retribuição. Se for fornecido, o método retorna ambos, um possível erro e a string da renderização. Quando um erro ocorre, o método invoca `next(err) internamente.

Tendo em vista a explicação acima a substituição do `render` para o código a seguir deverá resultar em sucesso na execução:

```
res.render('marcas', {marcas, tipos});
```

---

> [**Funções assíncronas**](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/funcoes_assincronas)
>
> A declaração **async function** define uma função assíncrona, que retorna um objeto [AsyncFunction](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/AsyncFunction).
>
> Você também pode definir funções assíncronas usando uma [expressão async function](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/async_function).
>
> Quando uma função assíncrona é chamada, ela retorna uma [Promise](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise). Quando a função assíncrona retorna um valor, a `Promise` será resolvida com o valor retornado. Quando a função assíncrona lança uma exceção ou algum valor, a `Promise` será rejeitada com o valor lançado.
>
> Uma função assíncrona pode conter uma expressão [await](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/await), que pausa a execução da função assíncrona e espera pela resolução da `Promise` passada, e depois retoma a execução da função assíncrona e retorna o valor resolvido.

---

> [**Atribuição via desestruturação (destructuring assignment)**](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Atribuicao_via_desestruturacao)
>
> A sintaxe de **atribuição via desestruturação (destructuring assignment)** é uma expressão `JavaScript` que possibilita extrair dados de arrays ou objetos em variáveis distintas.