# Como atribuir o resultado de uma Promise a uma variável?

Tags: javascript, node.js, promises

Mesmo lendo a esta [outra pergunta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/317069) do site, continuo não entendendo porque não consigo retirar um valor de dentro de uma `Promise`. Como faço esse tipo de atribuição?

A ideia é executar várias promessas (reunir dados para gerar uma informação). Deixo abaixo um exemplo no qual consigo imprimir os dados para o console, mas não consigo atribuir a variável `tam`.

```
function recuperaDados() {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    request.get('http://localhost:8080/api/tamanhos', (error, _, body) => {
      if (error) {
        reject(error);
      }
      resolve(body);
    });
  });
}

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
  // Quero que o resultado de `recuperaDados()` venha para cá.
  let tams;

  recuperaDados()
    .then((body) => {
      // Consigo imprimir ao console:
      console.log(body);

      // Mas esta atribuição não funciona:
      tams = body;
    })
    .catch(console.error);

  console.log(typeof tams); //-> undefined
  res.send(tams); // Não exibe nada.
});
```

Onde estou errando? Eu teria que fazer várias pomises, uma dentro da outra? Seguindo as melhores práticas, qual seria a melhor solução?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

TL;DR: Se você quiser seguir as boas práticas, não pode atribuir o valor resolvido de uma `Promise` para uma variável que esteja fora do `callback` do `then` ou `catch` ou da função assíncrona. Leia a resposta a seguir para entender o porquê.

---

O JavaScript é [*single-threaded<sup>[EN]</sup>*](https://www.red-gate.com/simple-talk/dotnet/asp-net/javascript-single-threaded/) e por isso, opera através de um [loop de eventos](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/EventLoop). Levando essa afirmação em conta, ele não pode esperar que uma `Promise` se resolva para continuar a execução do resto da aplicação *(diferentemente de linguagens como o PHP)*, já que isso bloquearia todo o loop de eventos, impedindo outras interações na página.

Levando em conta que uma `Promise` irá se concluir em algum momento que não temos ciência (daqui a 5 milissegundos, 5 segundos ou até mesmo mais tempo), não temos como definir o tempo que a promessa ficará "*carregando*". A forma mais correta de você acessar os dados resolvidos de uma `Promise` é através do [`then`](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/then), que receberá o valor resolvido, ou o [`catch`](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/catch), que realizará eventuais tratativas de erro.

Tenha ciência, no entanto, que apesar de que você pode sim atribuir o valor resolvido de uma promessa para fora do *callback* do `then`, essa **não é uma boa prática (e pode inclusive levar o seu código a erros)** justamente pelo fato de que, como disse acima, você não tem como determinar com precisão o tempo em que cada `Promise` irá demorar para ser concluída.

Então, seguindo as melhores práticas, para acessar os dados resolvidos de uma Promessa, você tem duas opções:

#### Utilizar o [`then`](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/then):

```js
app.get('/', (req, res) => {
  recuperaDados()
    .then((dados) => {
      // Você terá que tratar os dados aqui dentro.
      // Não poderá passar os dados da variável `dados` para fora
      // do escopo desse callback de nenhum modo. 

      // Note a seguir que eu posso fazer o uso dos dados da forma como eu desejar
      // dentro desse callback. Logo, não há motivo para querer levar a variável `dados`
      // para fora do escopo atual. :)
      res.send('Dados: ' + JSON.stringify(dados))
    })
})
```

#### Utilizar [função assíncrona](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/funcoes_assincronas):

Para utilizar [função assíncrona](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/funcoes_assincronas), você deve usar o operador [`await`](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/await) para aguardar a resolução das funções que retornam `Promise`:

```js
// Note abaixo que marquei a função como assíncrona adicionando o prefixo "async".
//           ↓↓↓↓↓
app.get('/', async (req, res) => {
  // O `await` irá bloquear o código *somente dentro dessa função* até que
  // o valor da promessa seja devidamente resolvido:
  const dados = await recuperaDados()

  // Como utilizamos o `await` acima, esse código só será executado
  // quando os dados da promessa estiverem "prontos":
  res.send('Dados: ' + JSON.stringify(dados))
})
```

Lembre-se de que ao usar funções assíncronas, você deve usar o `await` para que você aguarda a conclusão da `Promise` (resolução ou rejeição), caso contrário, você estará atribuindo à variável a promessa em si, e não o seu valor de resolução ou erro. O operador `await` vai **parar a execução dentro da função assíncrona** até que a `Promise` se resolva.

### Leitura complementar interessante ou para aprofundamento:

- [Promessas em JavaScript: uma introdução](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/primers/promises?hl=pt-br);
- [`Promise`](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise);
- [`Promise.prototype.then`](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/then);
- [`Promise.prototype.catch`](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/catch);
- [Funções assíncronas](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/funcoes_assincronas);
- [Operador `await`](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/await).