# Retorno de Request (Node.js)

Tags: javascript, node.js

Estou tentando consumir uma API com request, porém gostaria de saber como posso atribuir o retorno a uma variável. Aqui vai meu código:

```
var response
function getWeather() {
    request(url, function (error, response, body) {
        console.log(body)
        response = body
    })
}
console.log(response)
```

O console.log(body) me retorna o valor em string, porém, o console.log(response) retorna undefined. Gostaria que a variavel response captasse o conteúdo do body para eu manipular. Como posso fazer isso?

Comment: Você deve colocar o `console.log` dentro do callback. Não é recomendado tentar remover uma variável de dentro do escopo de uma chamada callback. Você pode entender melhor [nessa resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/379215/69296).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O ideal é que você dê um return no weather que consumiu pela API no método getWeather e assim usar o método getWeather onde deseja.

Por exemplo:

```
async function getWeather() {
    return request(url, function (error, response, body) {
        if (response.status === 200)
           return body

        return false
    })
}
```

*Obs: Não testei o código e não sei se request resolve uma Promise, caso for pode ser que o código não funcione. Mas é apenas para te dar uma noção.*

Posteriormente bastaria você chamar a função para consumir a API e já pegar o valor onde desejar.

```
const weather = await getWeather()
```

Entendeu o conceito?

Comment: Acredito haver um erro em seu exemplo. `await` só pode ser chamado dentro do escopo de uma função `async` veja a documentação [Mozilla Docs: async/await](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/funcoes_assincronas) ... e se fosse o caso de `getWeather()` ser **async** o retorno seria: `Promise.resolve(body)`

Comment: Da mesma forma como não foi passado um exemplo completo, apenas dei uma explicação geral, já que eu nunca usei e não uso o request. Mas ao chamar a função com await é necessário estar dentro de um async, lógico. É que talvez o amigo ainda não saiba muito bem a dor de cabeça da assincronidade do node rsrs ainda mais consumindo uma API.. haha pelo menos com o await ali ele poderia pesquisar mais a fundo. Mas a resposta sua resposta ficou bem completa, ele pode usa-la quase por completo no exemplo dele... Já dei um voto positivo nela! =]

Answer (score 2):

O seu "problema" consiste do fato de que esta requisição feita pelo módulo ser **assíncrona** ou seja: o pedido será realizado e posteriormente você obterá uma resposta, seja ela o corpo da solicitação ou um erro que ocorreu no pedido.

Você está declarando uma variável sem um conteúdo (`response`) na esperança de atribuir um valor a ela quando a resposta vier porém, esta acessando (usando) esta variável antes disto acontecer (`console.log`) ... sempre será `undefined`

Você deve utilizar uma função de **callback** para trabalhar sobre este valor, exemplo:

```
const request = require("request");

function getWeather(callback) {
    request(url, function (error, response, body) {
        callback(body)
    })
}

getWeather(function(responseBody) {
    console.log(responseBody)
})
```

Por padrão este módulo não trabalha com `Promise()` más, assim como descrito pelo próprio módulo você pode utilizar os pacotes adjacentes caso queira trabalhar sobre **"Promessas"** veja os links dos pacotes adjacentes:

https://www.npmjs.com/package/request#promises--asyncawait

Caso não queira utilizar pacotes extras saiba que podes fazer isso de maneira nativa utilizando o módulo nativo **utils** e "promissificando" o **request**:

```
const util = require('util')
const request = require("request");

const requestPromise = util.promisify(request);

function getWeather(url) {
    return requestPromise(url).then(response => {
        if ( response.statusCode === 200 ) {
            return response.body
        }
        return Promise.reject(response.statusCode)
    })
}    

getWeather('https://www.google.com').then(body => {
    console.log(body)
}).catch(e => console.log(e))
```

Como nem todos os possíveis códigos de status são um erro na requisição você deve tratá-los conforme realmente os queira, o exemplo acima apenas retornará o corpo da requisição caso o status seja igual a **200** e rejeitará todos os demais.

`Promise()` por natureza são funções "assíncronas" mas você pode usar **await** para trabalhar sobre um comportamento "síncrono" desde que esteja dentro de uma função **async**:

```
const util = require('util')
const request = require("request");
const requestPromise = util.promisify(request);    


async function done() {
    let response = await requestPromise('https://www.google.com')
    console.log(response.body)
}    

done()
```

No exemplo acima não há garantias de que a resposta terá uma propriedade **"body"** e não poderá fazer nenhum tratamento no caso de erro/falha além de que todo o código irá "esperar" a conclusão do pedido e um servidor pode demorar muito a responder.

Uma abordagem "melhor" seria tratar as possíveis falhas na requisição em um bloco `.catch()`:

```
const util = require('util')
const request = require("request");
const requestPromise = util.promisify(request);


async function done() {
    async function getWeather(url) {
        return requestPromise(url).then(response => {
            if ( response.statusCode === 200 ) {
                return response.body
            }
            return Promise.reject(response.statusCode)
        }).catch(err => {
            return err
        })
    }

    console.log(await getWeather('https://www.google.com'))
}

done()
```

---

**leitura**:

[Mozilla Docs: async/await](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/funcoes_assincronas)

Comment: Perfeita a explicação meu caro! Na realidade eu fiquei meio perdido em alguns conceitos do Node, eu consumi a API perfeitamente em PHP que é bem mais tranquilo, mas pesquisei mais sobre o async e o await e sobre o NODE em si e consegui compreender e aplicar, e gostei bastante também da abordagem que você utilizou na questão do tratamento de erros da requisição. O exemplo está bem completo e bem didático! Obrigado, e assim que finalizar vou fazer um tutorial de como consumi a API para os próximos que tiverem a mesma dúvida.