# Alguém sabe porque a lista continua vazia mesmo apos o await (Node.js)?

Tags: javascript, node.js

```
static async readAll(){
    const data = []
    await mysql.query('SELECT * FROM registro', (err, result, fields) => {
        if (err) throw err;
        result.forEach((doc) => {
            const registro = new Registro(doc);
            data.push(registro);
        });
    });
    console.log(data);
}
```

Mesmo apos eu dizer para "esperar" a execução do codigo ele não adiciona meu objeto ao meu array "data", alguem sabe como resolver?

Answer (score 2):

O método `mysql.query` provavelmente não é uma `Promise`, então usar o `await` não irá servir de nada.

Você deve tratar com o valor `data` **dentro do *callback***, dada a natureza assícrona do JavaScript. Quando você dá o `console.log(data)` fora do *callback*, a *query* provavelmente ainda está sendo carregada.

Veja uma demonstração desse fluxo assíncrono:

```js
console.log(1);

// Imagine o método `fetch` como algo que faz uma consulta ao banco de dados:
fetch('https://api.github.com/users/lffg')
  .then(() => console.log(2));
  
console.log(3);
```

Como você pode ver acima, o `console.log(3)` é exibido antes do `2`, já que esse último ainda está sendo "carregado", uma vez que está dentro de um *then*.

Desse modo, se você quiser trabalhar com os dados na sua função `readAll`, terá que fazê-lo dentro do *callback*:

```js
static readAll() {
  mysql.query('SELECT * FROM registro', (err, result, fields) => {
    if (err) throw err;

    const data = [];
    result.forEach((doc) => {
      const registro = new Registro(doc);
      data.push(registro);
    });

    // Aqui você terá acesso ao `data`. Sem problemas. :)
    console.log(data);
  });
}
```

Já se você quiser usar o valor como retorno do método, vale usar uma `Promise`, para que você possa usar `await` em outra parte do seu código:

```js
class MyService {
  static readAll() {
    // Note que o método `readAll` retorna uma nova promessa:
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      mysql.query('SELECT * FROM registro', (err, result, fields) => {
        if (err) reject(err);

        // Usei o `Array.prototype.map` para eliminar a necessidade do `forEach`.
        const data = result.map((doc) => new Registro(doc));

        // A promessa eventualmente irá se resolver com o valor `data`:
        resolve(data);
      });
    });
  }
}

// E em outra parte do código:
async function main() {
  const data = await MyService.readAll();
  console.log(data);
}
```

Para um maior aprofundamento, acho importante ler outros recursos sobre promessas, como:

- [Como atribuir o resultado de uma promise a uma variável?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/379212/como-atribuir-o-resultado-de-uma-promise-a-uma-vari%c3%a1vel/379215#379215)
- [Promessas em JavaScript: uma introdução](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/primers/promises?hl=pt-br);
- [`Promise`](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise);
- [`Promise.prototype.then`](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/then);
- [`Promise.prototype.catch`](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/catch);
- [Funções assíncronas](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/funcoes_assincronas);
- [Operador `await`](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/await).

E também vale a pena ler sobre o [`Array.prototype.map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map).