# Como exportar o conteúdo de uma promisse que está em um modulo para outro módulo?

Tags: javascript, node.js, promises

Tenho o seguinte módulo `getToken.js`:

```
var rp = require('request-promise');

const options = {
    url: 'https://meuservidor:8080/nifi-api/access/token',
    method: 'POST',
    gzip: true,
    rejectUnauthorized: false,
    headers: {
        'Accept-Encoding': 'gzip, deflate, br',
        'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8'
    },
    body: 'username=meuusuario&password=minhasenha'
}

rp(options)
    .then(function(body) {
        console.log(body)
    })
    .catch(function(err) {
        console.log(err)
    })
```

Como exportar o conteúdo do `console.log(body)` para outro módulo?

Comment: Só precisas de chamar `rp()` uma vez e queres exportar o valor de `body` ou queres chamar `rp` de outros módulos e receber `body`s diferentes?

Comment: Só preciso chamar o rp() uma vez e quero exportar o valor de body

Answer (score 0):

Em resumo, você não pode exportar o valor da resolução (ou rejeição) da promessa. Para saber mais sobre o porquê, leia [esta resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/379215/69296).  Assim, uma opção é exportar a própria `Promise`, e usar o `then` e/ou `catch` no módulo que a importar.

Então, no módulo que você exporta, você deve exportar a `Promise`. Portanto:

```js
// ...

// `rp` é uma função que retorna uma `Promise`.
module.exports = rp();
```

E para importar:

```js
const bodyPromise = require('./my-module.js');

bodyPromise.then((body) => /* Do stuff. */); // Não se esqueça do `catch`. :-)
```

Uma outra opção seria exportar a função `rp`, utilizando  `module.exports = rp`. Contudo, isso faria com que você tivesse que chamar essa função nos módulos que a importarem. Ao sempre exportar a `Promise` (o valor retornado pela função), você assume que o argumento passado `options` será sempre o mesmo. Se isso não for o que você precisa, você deve exportar a função, e não o seu retorno—a promessa.

Comment: Só consegui reproduzir o que queria em python, ficou assim: http://dontpad.com/oqfizempython

Comment: Python é uma linguagem. JavaScript é outra. Pelo fato de que módulos em JavaScript funcionam de forma síncrona, você não pode esperar a promessa se resolver para exportar um valor. Nem sempre a linguagem fará o que você precisa que ela faça... Você deve procurar algum jeito de resolver conforme as "limitações" (se é que isso é uma) da linguagem. Uma forma de se fazer isso é exportar a promessa diretamente.

Comment: Além disso, eu não sei programar em Python, mas creio que você conseguiu fazer em Python porque os métodos que você usou em Python são síncronos (penso que sejam), o que não é o caso no JavaScript... Se ainda assim não é o que você precisa, edite a sua pergunta adicionando mais detalhes para que eu possa te ajudar melhor. :-)