# Preciso associar variavel a um key do objeto NODEJS

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

Eu estou encontrando no database o seller correto, porem quando eu tento associar a variavel sellerSupport ao valor do objeto support dentro do user, ele me da undefined e eu nao consigo associar o valor.

```
    let sellerSupport;  
    User.findOne({fullName: seller}, function(err, user) {
        sellerSupport = user.support;
    })
```

Alguem saberia como corrigir isso?

Comment: O seu caso se trata de _callback_, e não `Promise`. Mas é a basicamente a mesma coisa e o motivo de você **não poder fazer isso** é o mesmo. A pergunta "[Como atribuir o resultado de uma promise a uma variável?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/379212/como-atribuir-o-resultado-de-uma-promise-a-uma-vari%c3%a1vel)" responde à sua questão? :)

Answer (score 0):

Você pode utilizar o Sequelize de forma assíncrona.

Exemplo 1:

```
async function userController(req, res) {
  //Meu código

  const userData = await User.findOne({fullName: seller});

  //Desestruturação
  const { support: sellerSupport } = userData;

  //Minha lógica...

};
```

Ou de maneira mais simples

Exemplo 2:

```
async function userController2(req, res) {
  //Meu código

  const userData = User.findOne({fullName: seller});

  const sellerSupport = userData.support;

  //Minha lógica...

};
```

É interessante procurar por conteúdos sobre callback e assincronismo.
Um abraço!