# Variável "esquece" que foi atribuída à outra e função retorna undefined

Tags: javascript, variáveis, javascript-eventos

```js
function pegarBotaoClicado (botoes) {
    let botaoClicado

    botoes.forEach(botao => {
        botao.addEventListener("click", function (e) {
             botaoClicado = botao
        })
    })

    return botaoClicado
}
```

Nessa função que criei o intuito é pegar o botão clicado dentro de um array de botões. O problema é que na linha `botaoClicado = botao`, era para a variável `botaoClicado` tomar o valor do botão. Isso acontece, usei o debug do navegador e por lá eu consigo ver que realmente a variável toma o valor.

O problema é que na hora de retornar essa variável, a função retorna `undefined`. Parece que esqueceu que foi atribuída a uma variável. Penso que o problema seja relacionado ao escopo, mas não faço ideia e já pesquisei muito.

Comment: Você não pode tentar tirar uma variável de dentro do _callback_.

Comment: eu nao posso fazer atribuição dentro da callback?

Comment: Você pode fazer atribuições. O que você _não pode fazer_ é tentar atribuir uma variável de dentro do _callback_ para fora dele. Poder fazer até pode, como você fez. Nenhuma exceção será lançada, mas é indubitável que comportamentos errados ocorrerão.

Comment: qual voce acha que seria uma solução? Sou praticamente iniciante ainda

Comment: Essa pergunta, apesar de se tratar de `Promise`, pode te dar uma ideia do porquê isso é errado: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/379212/como-atribuir-o-resultado-de-uma-promise-a-uma-vari%c3%a1vel/379215#379215

Comment: Muito provavelmente você não precisa de "pegar" o botão clicado. Basta colocar a sua lógica dentro do _callback_ de `addEventListener`, que só irá executar para os botões que forem clicados.

Comment: Eu sempre falo, mas não adianta, pegou moda. A maioria dos usos do `forEach()` são completamente desnecessários e o `for` normal funciona melhor. Essa função tem um monte de efeito colateral ruim e danoso, difícil de entender até para quem é experiente, fora a limitação de coisas que é fácil fazer com `for`. As pessoas gostam de *clever code*. O triste é que algumas pessoas ensinam isso para parecer mais inteligente e quem está aprendendo acha que é melhor. Até pode ser em casos bem específicos. E olha que eu gosto do estilo funcional.

Comment: se eu mudar para for resolve o problema?

Comment: O problema é que `.forEach()` é assíncrono e vc acaba retornando antes do loop terminar e com certeza de nada vai adiantar seu "evento" ... vc poderia esclarecer que tipo de matriz é "botoes" (um Arary de elementos ou um nodeList) e o que espera obter com o retorno, talvez assim consiga de fato uma ajuda