# Retornar Item de Array criada com função assíncrona

Tags: javascript, async

Com uma função assíncrona estou criando um array para receber os dados de uma API. Ao dar console.log(dados) consigo retornar corretamente todos os dados do array, mas ao tentar retornar apenas um item, como em console.log(dados[0]) é retornado como undefined. Como posso retornar apenas um item?

```js
var dados = [];

async function getContent() {
  try {
    const response = await fetch('http://localhost:3001/api/products?page=1');
    const data = await response.json();

    for (var i = 0; i < data.docs.length; i++) {
      dados[i]  
        = {
          'key': i + 1,
        'nome': "" + data.docs[i].name + "",
        'hs': data.docs[i].hs
      }
    }

  } catch (error) {
    console.log('error');
  }
}

getContent();

console.log(dados); // retorna os valores do array (como na imagem).

console.log(dados[0]); //retorna undefined
console.log(dados[1]); //retorna undefined
```

[image: Retorno no console]

Comment: Você chegou a tentar usar a palavra-chave `return` para retornar, por exemplo, `data.docs[0]`? Uma outra pergunta que pode te ajudar a compreender esse assunto é esta: [Como atribuir o resultado de uma promise a uma variável?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/379215/69296).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dois errados estão fazendo um certo no seu código.

Quando você faz `console.log(dados)`, não irá existir nada dentro desse array chamado `dados`. Você só está conseguindo visualizar o array preenchido por causa da forma que o console de desenvolvedor funciona.

O `console.log(dados)` não imprime o array de imediato no console, ele apenas passa a referência do array, e quando você tenta visualizar esse dado, o console irá buscar o array e imprimir o conteúdo atual.

Por essa mesma razão você não consegue visualizar o `console.log(dados[0])` e o `console.log(dados[1])`: o array nem está preenchido a esse ponto, e adicionalmente os indices `0` e `1` não existiam, então mesmo depois que o seu array for preenchido, o console não irá conseguir buscar essas referências.

O que você precisa fazer é esperar pela resolução da sua função assíncrona `getContent` antes de imprimir o `dados`:

```
var dados = [];

async function getContent() {
  try {
    const response = await fetch('http://localhost:3001/api/products?page=1');
    const data = await response.json();

    for (var i = 0; i < data.docs.length; i++) {
      dados[i]  
        = {
          'key': i + 1,
        'nome': "" + data.docs[i].name + "",
        'hs': data.docs[i].hs
      }
    }

  } catch (error) {
    console.log('error');
  }
}

async function main() {
    await getContent();

    console.log(dados);
    console.log(dados[0]);
    console.log(dados[1]);
}

main();
```

Preferencialmente, você também deveria gerar e retornar o array `dados` na função `getContent` ao invés de declara-lo como global.

Comment: Ao invés de usar uma variável global como `dados` para "passar" os dados de `getContent` para `main`, não seria simplesmente mais fácil retornar os dados da função `getContent` utilizando o `return`? Esse tipo de coisa me parece um _anti-pattern_... Além disso, ao utilizar variáveis globais desse modo, estado está sendo compartilhado indiscriminadamente, o que pode propiciar [condições de corrida](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/159342/o-que-%C3%A9-uma-condi%C3%A7%C3%A3o-de-corrida/159355).

Comment: @LuizFelipe, sim, foi o que eu comentei na ultima linha. O exemplo que eu criei foi seguindo a lógica da usuária para manter o mesmo raciocínio.