# Problemas para pegar os dados do Firebase Realtime Database

Tags: javascript, firebase, promises

Estou aprendendo a usar o Firebase e essa é meu primeiro projeto, mas quando tento colocar os valores do banco de dados em uma variável ela retorna `Promise { <pending> }`, o codigo em questão é esse:

```js
const firebase = require('firebase-admin');
const key = require('./teste-a43e2-firebase-adminsdk-3sd3256d0-adc6b.json');

firebase.initializeApp({
  credential: firebase.credential.cert(key),
  databaseURL: "https://teste-a43e2.firebaseio.com"
});

const data = firebase.database().ref('/date').once('value').then(snapshot => {
  let database = (snapshot.val()) || 'Anonymous';
  console.log(database);
  return database
});

console.log(data);
```

como o primeiro `console.log` mostra a função esta retornando os valores do banco de dados, mas o `data`esta recebendo uma promise e não os valores

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Isso se deve à natureza assíncrona do JavaScript. Você não consegue simplesmente remover um valor de "dentro" de uma _promise_ porque não é possível determinar quando o valor estará disponível. Eu explico um pouco melhor sobre como lidar com isso nesta outra pergunta: **[Como atribuir o resultado de uma promise a uma variável?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/379215/69296)**. Mas em resumo, você deve simplesmente lidar com os dados resolvidos de dentro do _callback_ do `then`. Você pode encadear várias promessas ou utilizar o `async/await` para organizar um pouco melhor o código, se necessário.

Comment: Isto responde à sua pergunta? [Como atribuir o resultado de uma promise a uma variável?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/379212/como-atribuir-o-resultado-de-uma-promise-a-uma-vari%c3%a1vel)