# console.log retornando "undefined" no then (fetch)

Tags: javascript, json, api, fetch

sou iniciante, aparentemente o "code" esta dentro de um id, n sei como capturar...v

```
const url = 'https://economia.awesomeapi.com.br/json/USD-BRL/'

fetch(url)
.then(resposta => resposta.json())
.then(dados => console.log(dados.code))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Se acessar a url no navegador, vai obter a seguinte resposta:

```
[
   {
      "code":"USD",
      "codein":"BRL",
      "name":"Dólar Comercial",
      "high":"5.3861",
      "low":"5.3861",
      "varBid":"0.0003",
      "pctChange":"0.01",
      "bid":"5.3858",
      "ask":"5.3864",
      "timestamp":"1604957402",
      "create_date":"2020-11-09 19:00:03"
   }
]
```

Ou seja, o `[` indica que é um array, por isso precisa acessar pelo índice, por exemplo `dados[0]`. Adicionei ao exemplo um comando `for`, para que se houver mais de um item na resposta, permite percorrer cada um (para isso, usei a propriedade `length`, que retorna o tamanho do array):

```js
const url = 'https://economia.awesomeapi.com.br/json/USD-BRL/'

fetch(url)
.then(resposta => 
   resposta.json())
.then(dados => {
  for(i=0; i<dados.length; i++) {
    console.log(dados[i].code);
    console.log(dados[i].name);
  }
})
```

Comment: Obrigado, porém agora me surgiu outra duvida, como posso armazenar esse resultado em uma variável?

Comment: @HérbertTavares, a resposta simples para essa pergunta é: não "armazene" (pelo menos não na forma como você parece tentar fazer). Jamais tente "tirar" um valor de "dentro" de uma `Promise` (ou uma cadeia de promessas). Ao fazer isso, você está indo contra a natureza assíncrona do JavaScript. Detalhes adicionais são dados em [Como atribuir o resultado de uma `Promise` a uma variável?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/379215/69296).

Comment: `dados` já é uma variável com tudo, o que mais precisa? se precisa passar isso para fora do método que retorna da *promise*, precisa criar uma variável fora no escopo fora desse método, ou o mais comum é usar isso no html, para exibir por exemplo, e isso pode fazer no próprio método usando a variável `dados`