# React - Formulário aproveitado do PHP dando erro "CANNOT POST"

Tags: php, mysql, react, formulário

Olá, estou tendo um problema ao reaproveitar um formulário que eu costumava usar em minha aplicação html de forma que eu mandasse os dados para um arquivo PHP inserir no meu banco de dados MYSQL. Infelizmente não estou conseguindo aproveitar esse mesmo formulário em React por estar aparecendo um erro: "cannot post". Poderiam me informar se é possível eu enviar um formulário de uma aplicação React para um arquivo PHP para inserção dos dados? Abaixo meu código:

```
import React from 'react';

function Pedidos() {

    return(
        <>
            <div className="row-sm-6" >
                <div className="col" >
                    
                    <form className="col-lg-12" action='http://localhost:8080/React6/fse/src/php/processamento_pedidos.php' method="POST" >

                        <div className="col-12">
                            <input className="form-control" type="nome_cliente" id="nome" name="nome_cliente" placeholder="Nome completo" required />
                        </div>

                        <br />

                        <div className="col-12">
                            <input className="form-control" type="endereco" id="endereco" name="endereco" placeholder="Endereço para entrega" required />
                        </div>

                        <br />

                        <div className="col-12">
                            <input className="form-control" type="email" id="email" name="email" placeholder="Email para contato" required />
                        </div>

                        <br />

                        <div className="col-12">
                            <input className="form-control" type="telefone" id="telefone" name="telefone" placeholder="Telefone para contato" required />
                        </div>

                        <br />

                        <div className = "opcoes_produtos">
                        <label for="">Selecione seu Produto:</label>
                        <select className="form-control" name = "produto">
                            <option value="FOGAO 4 BOCAS">Fogão 4 bocas</option>
                            <option value="FOGAO ATLAS">Fogão ATLAS</option>
                            <option value="MICROONDAS ELETROLUX">Microondas Eletrolux</option>
                            <option value="MICROONDAS PHILCO">Microondas Philco</option>
                            <option value="MICOONDAS CONSUL">Microondas Consul</option>
                            <option value="GELADEIRA BRASTEMP">Geladeira Brastemp</option>
                            <option value="GELADEIRA TRÊS PORTAS">Geladeira três portas</option>
                            <option value="GELADEIRA DODGE">Geladeira Dodge</option>
                            <option value="MAQUINA DE LAVAR ELECTROLUX">Maquina de Lavar Eletrolux</option>
                            <option value="MAQUINA DE LAVAR PHILCO">Maquina de Lavar Philco</option>
                            <option value="LAVADORA DE PRATOS TORPENTE">Lavadora de Pratos Torpente</option>
                            <option value="LAVADORA DE PRATOS ELECTROLUX">Lavadora de Pratos Electrolux</option>
                        </select>
                        </div>
                        

                        <div className = "quantidade_produtos"> 
                        <label for="">Selecione a quantidade:</label>
                        <select className="form-control" name="quantidade">
                            <option value="1">1</option>
                            <option value="2">2</option>
                            <option value="3">3</option>
                            <option value="4">4</option>
                            <option value="5">5</option>
                            <option value="6">6</option>
                            <option value="7">7</option>
                            <option value="8">8</option>
                            <option value="9">9</option>
                            <option value="10">10</option>
                        </select>
                        </div>

                        <br />

                        <button type="submit" className="btn btn-success"><b>Enviar Pedido</b></button>   
                        <br />
                        <br />

                    </form>
                </div>                    
            </div>
        </>                     
    )   
}
export default Pedidos;
```

Comment: A estratégia é outra é com `Ajax` o formulário não pode ser submetido como tradicionalmente é feito.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

O [react](/questions/tagged/react) trabalha de forma diferente e precisa enviar informações com [ajax](/questions/tagged/ajax), não como está na pergunta do modo tradicional pelo próprio `<form>`, além do mais o seu formulário não guarda as informações relativas a cada item de tela ou seja, os estados e isso é um erro na construção do seu código, vou então propor um exemplo mínimo para que tu possa entender:

```js
function Main() {
  const [name, setName] = React.useState('');
  const [sexo, setSexo] = React.useState('');
  const handleSubmit = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    console.log({name, sexo});
  }
  const handleChange = (e, fn) => {
    fn(e.target.value);
  }
  return (  
    <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>        
      <div>
        Name: 
        <input 
            name="name" 
            value={name} 
            onChange={e => handleChange(e, setName)}
        />
      </div>
      <div>
        Name: 
        <select name="sexo" 
            onChange={e => handleChange(e, setSexo)}>
          <option>Escolha</option>
          <option>Masculino</option>
          <option>Feminimo</option>
        </select>
      </div>
      <div>
        <button>Enviar</button>
      </div>
    </form>
  )
}
ReactDOM.render( <Main />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.9.0/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.9.0/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.5.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-TX8t27EcRE3e/ihU7zmQxVncDAy5uIKz4rEkgIXeMed4M0jlfIDPvg6uqKI2xXr2" crossorigin="anonymous">
<div id="root">Carregando ...</div>
```

nesse exemplo digite nos campos e depois pressione o botão com a etiqueta `Enviar` e recebe os valores das informações do formulário.

Para enviar para o seu [back-end](/questions/tagged/back-end) como por exemplo: [POST Request with Fetch API?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39565706/post-request-with-fetch-api)
 outro exemplo [POST Request with Fetch API?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/481526/console-log-retornando-undefined-no-then-fetch).

No seu caso bem especifico no código exemplo:

```
const handleSubmit = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    let formData = new FormData();
    formData.append('name', name);
    formData.append('sexo', sexo);
    fetch("http://localhost:8080/React6/fse/src/php/processamento_pedidos.php",
       {
            body: formData,
            method: "post"
       }
    );
}
```

<sub>***Referencia:*** [How do I post form data with fetch api?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46640744/6797930)</sub>

***Resumindo:*** para [react](/questions/tagged/react) a coisa muda completamente de figura, e precisa escrever código que o [react](/questions/tagged/react) entenda e possa proporcionar o que é preciso para enviar um conjunto de informações do seu [front-end](/questions/tagged/front-end) para o seu [back-end](/questions/tagged/back-end). Se quiser também colocar um formulário que verifique as entradas de dados utilize [React Hook Form](https://react-hook-form.com/) que vai possibilitar um diferencial na maneira de trabalhar com informações já previamente tratadas para o seu [back-end](/questions/tagged/back-end).

Comment: Um erro básico que eu estava cometendo era a porta pela qual eu estava mandando o formulario. No React por padrão é usada a porta 3000, e em meu PHPMyadmin e Mysql usavam a porta 8080. 
Resolvi o problema mudando as portas e me atentando melhor ao direcionamento, o qual eu tinha renomeado as pastas. Muito Obirgado!