# Como incrementar uma variável externa a um callback em NodeJS?

Tags: mysql, node.js

Olá!

Desejo incrementar a variável hierarquia, mas não consigo fazer.

Alguém pode me ajudar?

```js
 function getHierarquia(id, req, res) {
     var hierarquia = "";
     res.locals.connection.query('SELECT id, owner_id FROM users WHERE owner_id = ?', [id], function (error, results, fields) {
         if (error) {} else {
             results.forEach(element => {
                hierarquia += "," + getHierarquia(element['id'], req, res)
             });
         }
     })
     return hierarquia
 }
```

Comment: Qual a mensagem de erro retornada?

Comment: Não retorna nenhum erro, só não da para incrementar. Ele não entende como uma varável que faz parte do escopo.

Comment: Você está tratando código assíncrono como se fosse síncrono, o que é um erro "silencioso". Procure entender o que é um [_callback_](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/27177/69296) em JavaScript...

Comment: O seu caso é de _callback_, mas promessas podem ser utilizadas para explicar porque você não pode fazer esse tipo de coisa também. Veja mais em: [Como atribuir o resultado de uma promise a uma variável?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/379212/69296).

Comment: Como você está tentando incrementar ela dentro do callback da query, dentro deste callback a hierarquia não tem referência mesmo. 

Você pode colocar a query dentro de uma promise em outra função, e a partir do retorno dela tratar a hierarquia. 

Não testei aqui, mas talvez seja possível utilizar o "bind" no seu método query para incluir nele a referencia da hierarquia...